# Why creating a variable of a type "IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar" doesn't need a NEW keyword?

Tags: c#, class, object, ienumerable

If we have written a class called `MyClass` and need an object of it's type, we would go

```
var myVar = new MyClass();
```

and also if our `MyClass` has an `IEnumerable` interface we again need the `new` keyword such as:

```
class myClass : IEnumerable {...}
var myVar = new MyClass();
```

what about a situation when our class, `MyClass` is not used as one but as a *type* to instantiate a new variable of say:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar;
```

I would say we should clearly get an ***error*** if we go

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar = new IEnumerable<MyClass>();
```

but trying to understand the logic behind this. How this enumeration set of objects get created in this situation?

Comment: C# *and* C++? Why not throw in Java and PHP to complete the merry round of languages we should guess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning to use Interfaces effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701345/learning-to-use-interfaces-effectively)

Comment: @all, despite reading your recommended duplicated before and after I published the question, I still learned from the answer given for this question. My best regards for the people who value knowledge over curiosity but never given a though about which caused the other.

Comment: Please vote up for this comment, in the favor of me taking this question down if you think it will be no use for the future reader. I learned what I needed to and don't mind deleting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between *declaring* a variable and *instantiating* an object.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar;
```

Just declares a variable. No instantiation has occurred. If you were to hover over this variable with the debugger, it would be null. This line is also valid:

```
MyClass myVar;
```

You still need to instantiate `IEnumerable` with a derived type to use it:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar = new List<MyClass>();
```

Note that your line would not compile, because you cannot instantiate an interface or abstract class.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar = new IEnumerable<MyClass>();  //Does not compile!
```

You also seem to be confused about the `MyClass` in `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. This is just a generic type parameter, again, nothing is instantiated.

To speak to return values, the following code is totally valid:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar = someFunction();
myVar = new List<MyClass>();
```

However, `someFunction` would need to instantiate (or generate via LINQ) a class that derives from `IEnumerable`, or else this would just assign null again. I'm not sure what you mean by "instantiated and allocated by the value in one step", so its hard to say :). Functions just modularize code, there isn't any magic. For it to return a valid value, it has to have one in the first place or otherwise make one itself.

Comment: can you allocate a return value of a method which is of a type `IEnumerable<MyClass>` to `myVar` variable before you perform this line `IEnumerable<MyClass> myVar = new List<MyClass>();`? would it instantiated AND been allocated with the value in one step?

Comment: @Mehrad do you know what is an interface ? let's assume you instantiate the interface, what would you have ? methods without implementation ? interfaces don't provide any implementation, they are just contracts, classes implement interfaces and you instantiate them.

Comment: @Mehrad, not sure what your second question was about but yes you can assign it to a return value. See my edit for more details. Selmans comment about interfaces is spot on, if you have questions about the nature of an interface, please ask!

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerable is an interface, you can't instantiate it. You'd have to use a concrete class like List.